# How can I get Predicate<T> values on a Lambda Expression?

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following methods:

```
private List<T> GetEntities<T>(T entity) {
    // ...
}
```

and

```
public virtual List<T> Find<T>(Predicate<T> match) {
    // ...
}
```

How can I get the values of the lambda expression in the `Predicate<T>`?

I would like to do something like:

```
var result = Find<MyObject>(o => o.Name == "Something")
```

and in the `Find` method I would:

```
public virtual List<T> Find<T>(Predicate<T> match) {
    // ...
    string name = myObj.Name  // equals to "Something"        
    return GetEntities<T>(myObj) //Note that here is my object with the parameters passed via lambda
    // ...
}
```

How can I do this?

**Edit:** There is already a method that receives MyObject, **I just want a method that I can use lambda expressions, without instantiating an object just to filter an entity**. No idea if I use Func or Predicate

**Edit 2:** As requested, here is a concrete example of what i would achieve:

Currently, when I want to retrieve an object with specific filters, I use:

```
Person p = new Person() { Name = "John" };
var result = GetEntities<Person>(p);
```

What I like to do:

```
var result = Find<Person>(p => p.Name = "John");
```

**however**, internally would like to continue using the previous method, I would just turn up the expression into a object and then use `GetEntities<Person>(p)`

**Conclusion:**
I made a really lot of confusion with predicates and Func's. I thought I could treat them as objects, but are expressions and my question completely ran off the concept of these elements.

Comment: `match` doesn't have any values associated with it.

Comment: What do you mean by "the values of Predicate"? What do you have? Any reason you want to use `Predicate<T>` rather than just `Func<T, bool>` and Enumerable.Where?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `How can i get the values of Predicate`?

Comment: I edited the post to better understanding

Comment: You need to walk the expression tree... but what do you want that for?... there could be better easier simpler options to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Why does `Find` take a `Predicate` instead of a `MyObject`? What if the caller passes `o => o.Name.StartsWith("So")`, what should happen then?

Comment: There is already a method that receives MyObject, I just want a method that I can use lambda expressions, without instantiating an object just to filter

Comment: Can you give a *concrete* example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: You can't do what you want. You have to either change the `GetEntities` method or access the underlying collection directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the signature and usage, following code is what I inferred for you. It compiles, however, **it's incorrect for use**.

- Classes

  ```
  public partial class MyObject {
      public String Name;
  }

  public partial class MyGeneric<U> where U: MyObject {
      private List<T> GetEntities<T>(T entity) where T: U {
          throw new NotImplementedException(); // not implemented yet
      }

      public virtual List<T> Find<T>(Predicate<T> match) where T: U {
          foreach(var myObj in m_List)
              if(match(myObj as T)) {
                  // ...
                  var name=myObj.Name;
                  // ...
                  return this.GetEntities(myObj as T);
              }

          return new List<T>();
      }

      List<U> m_List;
  }
  ```
- Test

  ```
  var myGeneric=new MyGeneric<MyObject>();
  var result=myGeneric.Find<MyObject>(o => o.Name=="Something");
  ```

Here're something I'd like to tell:

1. You might misunderstood of generic.

   As you see the class `MyGeneric` and those two method, all have constraints. From the usage of your code, almost cannot go without these constraints, but this is just unnecessarily complicated.
2. You might misunderstood of `Predicate<T>` and also lambda expressions

   The definition of `Predicate<T>` is

   ```
   public delegate bool Predicate<T>(T obj);
   ```

   That is, it's a delegate. `obj` is the argument *pass to* the delegate. Therefore you cannot get `obj` with a different context. However, you can do something like

   ```
   MyObject x;
   var myGeneric=new MyGeneric<MyObject>();
   var result=myGeneric.Find<MyObject>(o => (x=o).Name=="Something");
   ```

   Here `x` references to `o`, but with your `Find` method, it's not possibly to do. So the object pass to the `Predicate<T>`, must already be somewhere you can access it, otherwise you can never.

I post with the code that demonstrates what the compilable syntax of statement that you can do, and even possibly works. But I **STRONGLY** suggest that **DON'T** do something like this.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I was making a lot of confusion with predicates and Delegates. Your example was simple and clear!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, your second method should be something like this:

```
public virtual List<T> Find<T>(Expression<Predicate<T>> match)
{
    return _myCollection.Where(match).ToList();
}
```

You can then pass a lambda expression into the method and get a list of matches back.

Comment: No, I wanna get the values passed on the lambda expression and use them to call another method that have same return type

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public virtual List<T> Find<T>(Func<T,bool> match)
{
   return lst.Where(match).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, this would be proper:

```
public virtual List<T> Find(T myObj)
{
    return GetEntities(myObj);
}
```

You need to pass predicate (`Func<T, bool>`) only if you want to filter item from IEnumerable, and you don't have any IEnumerable in your question. If you would have IEnumerable then:

```
private IEnumerable<T> _list;
public virtual List<T> Find(Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    T myObj = _list.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
    return GetEntities(myObj);
}
```

To expand a bit, yours `o => o.Name == "Something"` is equivalent to:

```
private bool Filter(MyObject enumeratedObject)
{
    return enumeratedObject.Name == "Something";
}
```

It doesn't contain any value until enumeration happens and starts calling Filter(...) for each element of the list.

Comment: It´s not exactly what I need. I will not use the expression to filter a List. I want use the expression to transform it in a object. I just need the values of the expression...

Comment: Then read again my answer. Expression is basically a method, it has no value. Do you have any value in "Filter" function above? No. -You have misconception about the way expressions work.

Comment: Yes, now I could understand.